# DisplayLink Screen Saver Issues

Tags: macos, screensaver, displayport

I am running OSX Lion 10.7.5 (can't upgrade yet due to corp policy) on my MBP 13" 2011.  I run with the lid closed connected to two displays:

- HP 24" via DisplayPort/DVI adapter
- Dell 24" via Diamond BVU195 USB/DVI adapter

**Problem:**  Intermittently, when I go to lock my screen (an Automator app that starts the screen saver), the screen saver won't start.  If I unplug the DisplayLink from the USB port, this instantly fixes the issue.  I can then reconnect the DisplayLink and the screen saver appears on both screens simultaneously.  Likewise, sometimes when I return to my desk and go to unlock my screen, the display hangs; it's black on both screens with visible mouse cursor but no image.  If I unplug the DisplayLink, again this immediately fixes the issue.

I've made sure I'm on the latest DisplayLink driver.  What else can I do to fix this so I don't have to frequently disconnect the DisplayLink device?

Answer (score 1):

I also noticed screensaver problems after installing a USB-DisplayLink adapter on my Mid 2012 MacBookPro.  Except my problem is that periodically screensaver kicks in even though I've been typing and mousing.  There are screensaver error messages in /var/log/system.log but I'm not sure they are related to this issue.

All screens except the DisplayLink screen blank out.  FWIW, I use a USB keyboard almost exclusively, and wonder if that is part of the problem.